# Error When calling stored procedure in python - Using MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have a MySQL stored procedure called test which accepts one argument.
 I can execute the stored procedure from python 2.7x using below code

```
data='Teststr'
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("CALL test('{0}')".format(data))
```

But when I use

```
data='Teststr'
cur = db.cursor()
cur.callproc('test',data)
```

I am encountering

`OperationalError: (1318, 'Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE MyDb.test; expected 1, got 7')`

Looks like python treats each character as one argument. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `cur.callproc('test', (data,))` to pass a tuple of 1 element

eg:

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> len(a) # just a
5
>>> len( (a) ) # still just a
5
>>> len( (a,) ) # single element tuple containing a
1
```